# Can't reach PHP variable in if statement

Tags: php, variables

I'm having a problem with the following code. The variable $houseid appears as empty in the second if statement but can be called in the first. I need the $houseid variable to be reached in the second if statement. I have tested it outside the both if's and in the first and it appears to work fine in both.

```
$landlordid = $_SESSION['landlordid'];

$con = mysqli_connect("mysql1616int.cp.blacknight.com","***","***","***"); // Connect to the MySQL server

$mysql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM houseInfo WHERE landlordID = '{$landlordid}'");


    echo '<form method="POST" action=""><select name="pickhouseid">';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mysql)){
      echo '<option value="' . $row['houseID'] . '">'. $row['housename'] . '</option>';
      }

    echo '</select> 
    <input type="submit" name="houseselect"  value="Select">
    </form>';
    echo "<br>";

    $houseid = $_POST['pickhouseid']; ///where house is set.

    if(isset($_POST['houseselect'])){
    echo "<form method='POST' action=''><select name='services'><option value='gas1'>Gas Reading</option>
            <option value='water1'>Water Reading</option><option value='elec1'>Electricity Reading</option>
            </select><input type='submit' value='Select'></form>";

    echo "<br>";
    echo $houseid; /// returns correct value
    }
    if (($_POST['services']) == 'gas1') { 
    echo "something";
    echo $houseid; ///doesn't work, appears as empty.
    }
```

Can anyone help with this problem? thank you.

Comment: Turn on error reportinhg: at the top of the script: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_NOTICE);` and re-test.

Comment: Firstly, I'd remove your database credentials from the question...

Comment: what is your exact output? Do you see the work 'something' ? I think your second if isn't entered. And in any way it has too much parantheses. `if (($_POST['services']) == 'gas1') ` could just be `if ($_POST['services'] == 'gas1') `

Comment: Since an edit is already pending I can't edit it, but please remove your db-server info and credentials as Jasarien said!

Comment: I removed the database credentials from the question, as @Jasarien pointed out correctly. Nevertheless, they can still be viewed through the edit history. You should definitely change those settings (especially username and password) as soon as possible.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I already filed an edit for it. I guess you rejected it?! It is quite frustrating to see my edits rejected in favor of higher ranking users' edits, as it keeps adding up to my reject count.

Comment: @nl-x I'm sorry your edit was rejected. I edited the post before any edits where suggested and I didn't reject yours. There was an edit pending after I edited the question but I didn't review it. If you feel like your edits are rejected very often, please start a topic on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @insertusernamehere Maybe... But if you're trying to connect there, you'll notice that the port isn't open in the firewall.

Comment: @bwoebi I didn't actually test the connection. :)

Comment: Use prepared statements to insert variable values into SQL, don't insert them manually.

Comment: all details changed, thanks for heads up!

Comment: Regarding the problem, I need the houseid that is first pulled to the variable from the first form to be kept in houseid variable. why would it be changed?

Comment: I have destroyed the revisions of this question that included the credentials, so they're no longer visible. Obviously you should still change the login details (or more precisely, you should already have done this at this point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form only submits what's in this form, not what's in another form on the page.

`$houseid` (in your last if) should be now `NULL` so echoing it should be output nothing.

So add the information about the `$houseid` into the other form. `$_POST` data aren't passed through multiple requests.

```
echo "<form method='POST' action=''><select name='services'><option value='gas1'>Gas Reading</option>
        <option value='water1'>Water Reading</option><option value='elec1'>Electricity Reading</option>
        </select><input type='submit' value='Select' />
        <input type='hidden' value='$houseid' name='houseid' /> <!-- here was added -->
       </form>";
```

Comment: yes, this is what i was thinking, that second if is only hit if the second form is submitted, which currently has no houseid

Comment: @user2311282 Then click please on the green bordered form left from my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

wow, is that possible? I see no reason why $houseid, should return empty, except if the condition returns false, try echoing something else (a string) in the if statement block and see if it appears, I really think the if statement returns false anyway.

Comment: the second if is based on the input of his second form, so houseid is wiped when the new form is submitted

Comment: how can I store houseid so that it is not wiped by the new form?